# MBP dedicated GPU stuck in high power state - system kexts not loading

Tags: macbook-pro, gpu, temperature

Here comes another dedicated GPU (dGPU) issue on my Late 2013 15" MacBook Pro!

**Problem:**

My NVIDIA GeForce GT 750M is not able to go into its lowest power state once automatic graphics switching is toggled on and then back off (iGPU being used, then dGPU).

This is confirmed by the reported power use by the "GPU Rail" metric in HWSensors (HWMonitor) at idle of 17W. When first booting with automatic graphics switching disabled (dGPU on), the idle power draw is 3W. After toggling automatic graphics switching on and back off (dGPU on), the card is at 17W idle forever until the next reboot.

This is also confirmed by the idle temperatures rising from low 40c's to high 50c's once it's stuck at 17W.

This is a problem because it also heats up my CPU +10c when dGPU is enabled and just idling, due to the fact that they share a heat pipe. The extra heat is also problematic when connecting an external 4k monitor which makes the whole computer get too hot. Many people have reported issue with overheating trying to run a second high resolution monitor. Finally, an extra 13W of unnecessary power draw has a huge negative effect on battery life.

**UPDATE:**

I discovered this problem is due to some system kernel extensions not loading. I installed Catalina fresh on an external drive and that fixed my dGPU being stuck in a higher power state.

I compared the system kernel extensions loaded on the fresh Catalina install with those loaded on the problematic install and made a list of all the kexts that did not load in the problematic Catalina install. The problem is that the system is not loading these kexts from /system/library/extensions:

IOPlatformPluginFamily.kext/contents/plugins/x86platformplugin.kext
IOPlatformPluginFamily.kext/contents/plugins/ioplatformpluginlegacy.kext
IOPlatformPluginFamily.kext/contents/plugins/acpi_smc_platformplugin.kext
IOPlatformPluginFamily.kext/contents/plugins/x86platformshim.kext
applegraphicspowermanagement.kext
appleplatformenabler.kext

In fact my issue is fixed by simply just loading x86platformplugin.kext:

```
sudo kextload IOPlatformPluginFamily.kext/contents/plugins/x86platformplugin.kext
```

However it's probably best to load all of those that are present on a clean Catalina install and not present on my problematic install.

After loading x86platformplugin.kext manually, toggling on the 750M dGPU results in it being able to use its low power state, consuming just 3W at idle compared to 17W otherwise.

**Why aren't these kexts loading on my problematic Catalina install? How do I get these kexts to load automatically after reboot?**

Comment: If your CPU and/or GPU are all operating within spec, I don't see what problem you actually looking to solve.  In other words, *what are you comparing these values to*?  What's your baseline for comparison?

Comment: I'm comparing the high power consumption to other MacBook Pros with this GPU, and the power consumption of the dGPU on my own machine, after first boot, or in safe mode, where it is normal. Please see my update.

Comment: Still no baseline.  You can’t say there is a problem by evaluating your subject machine in different modes.  As for “other MacBook Pros” you provide no reference.  You don’t even have a defined problem which would have a practical solution.t

Comment: @Allan What do you mean no baseline? The dGPU uses 3W of power when booted with dGPU active (graphics switching off). As soon as you toggle the switching on, dGPU switches off. When you toggle switching back off (dGPU on), it is stuck at consuming 17W idle.

Comment: How can i put this so you understand....  17W at idle.  So what?  There’s no context.  How do you know it’s idle?  There’s no display of activity or non-activity.  How do you know (and can show) this is abnormal behavior?  Simply saying it does X at idle and sits at 48C is irrelevant. For the record, thermal shutoff is around 100C so it’s well within operating parameters.

Comment: You can view GPU processor load with activity manager. There is no load. I know it's abnormal behavior because I can see that both power consumption of the dGPU and the dGPU core voltage go up and never come back down, after toggling dGPU off and back on. This is correlated in the temperature readings. Please read my post in its entirety if you want to continue helping. I don't need you to convince me everything is okay. I am sure it is not okay. Temperature is not the only concern. An extra 10W has a huge battery impact. I would like to find a solution.